# Mathematical Expression for Limiting Molar Conductivity

Tags: physical-chemistry, conductivity

I have been fiddling around with the theory of electrolytes, specifically molar conductivity, and ways of calculating limiting molar conductivity $\Lambda^0$.

I was able to come up with the following expression:

$$\Lambda^0 = \frac{\lambda}{mT}|z_+z_-|\, ,$$

where $m$ – mass of a single ion in solution (in $\pu{kg}$); $T$ – absolute temperature (in $\pu{K}$); $z_i$ – charge of a single ion (positive or negative); $\lambda$ is a constant given by

$$\lambda = \frac{N_\mathrm{A}he^2}{k_\mathrm{B}} = \frac{hF^2}{R} = \pu{7.42e-25 S kg m2 K mol-1}\, .$$

The above formula works for some chemical species, but fails for others.

Using my formula, $\Lambda^0$ for $\ce{HCl}$ at $\pu{298 K}$ ($m = \pu{6.06e-26 kg}$) is $\pu{0.0411 S m2 mol-1}$, which agrees well with the experimental value of $\pu{0.0426 S m2 mol-1}$.

Constants in the expression for $\lambda$ should be familiar to anyone who studies physical chemistry.

Have I found a new (easier!) approach of calculating $\Lambda^0$, or is my discovery just a coincidence (or, has this already been discovered)?

If it is indeed novel, any ideas on how to get a more accurate formula?

**EDIT (in response to closed post)**: Theory suggests that the above equation should also depend on the (dimensionless) dielectric constant (relative permittivity) of water (when dealing with aqueous solutions) which is 78.4 at 298 K, and this is also expressed in the comments.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you have any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Did you come across your expression by guesswork, or does it have some physical motivation? The latter might present a path for further generalization. Do you notice a pattern among the species for which your expression is accurate and among the species for which it is not? If you do, that might tell you about what interactions you should consider to get a better approximation.

Comment: Actually, based on electrolyte theory, limiting molar conductivity increases with temperature. In my expression, it is inversely proportions to temperature... haven't found anything to explain this yet... but it's remarkable that the expression has the same order of magnitude and correct units nonetheless.

Comment: Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown. I see you are an advanced $\rm \LaTeX$ user, but MathJax is a bit different:)

Comment: I actually determined the equation from guesswork, so I know of no way to verify it from theory.

Comment: Why do you have Planck's constant (h) in the equation? Is this a QM version of the classical equation?

Comment: h is indeed Planck's constant. There is no classical equation - it just so happens that the combination of constants that comprise the expression for $\lambda$ is close in magnitude to the mass of a single ion of a chemical species. In actuality, molar conductivity increases with increasing temperature. The above expression suggests an inverse relationship.

Comment: As well, the result of using the above equation is that it gives the same order of magnitudes as typical values for molar conductivity.

Comment: In your equation, the permittivity is missing. What is the relation of your equation to the usual equation of physical chemistry which uses a something similar expression for the activity coefficient?